# Symbol 'IllegalArgumentException' is inaccessible from here

Tags: java, android, android-studio, illegalargumentexception

I have two projects in Android studio: `model` and `app`.
`model` is written completely in java, graddle file starts with `apply plugin: 'java'`
`app` is written in android-java and depends on `model`. The graddle file starts with `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

I can insert this snippet:

```
/**
 * Debugging
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             if illegal == true
 */
private void debug(boolean illegal){
    if (illegal)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("tu");
}
```

anywhere in `app` and there are no errors. However when I insert it anywhere in `model` I get an error: `Symbol 'IllegalArgumentException' is inaccessible from here` and upon clicking 'more'
`Inspection info: This inspection points out unresolved references inside javadoc`
I can however compile, run without problems.

My Android-studio version is 3.4. I do not remember having this problem with the version I used before but I'm not sure which version that was.

Comment: I get it too; on a code base that did not have that before. I don't get it! I will say the error is in the javadoc @throws ..

Comment: Did you try checking the box Declaration has javadoc

Comment: @ManojPerumarath Thanks for the hint! `[shift] [shift] declaration javadoc` offers a switch for 'Javadoc: Declaration has problems in Javadoc references'. When I switch it off, the error goes away. But that's just suppressing the error message, right? How do I correctly specify an IllegalArgumentException?

Comment: Did you try running the project again, are you facing the same issue again

Comment: @ManojPerumarath When I uncheck the box 'Javadoc: Declaration has problems in Javadoc references' the error messages are gone, I don't even need to run the project again. 
But I'm confused: I've aways written throws declarations in the javadoc like that. Am I doing javadoc wrong? As I understand unchecking the box just makes that the error message is no longer displayed. But what is the point of the error message? What would be correct javadoc if I didn't want to uncheck the box?

Comment: I'm having the same issues, it must be a bug in the latest version of AS, right?

Answer (score 7):

I believe there is nothing wrong with your code. I can see the same error in my project. There is a bug in Android Studio (IntelliJ Idea), an issue has already been created: [Javadoc inspection "Declaration has problems in Javadoc reference" wrongly marks types as inaccessible.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-207715) So the only option is either switching off the check, or ignoring the error unless you suffer from OCD.